# Where to place the all() selector with a variable

Tags: jquery, variables

I have a list like this:

```
<ul>
  <li id="foo">foo</li>
  <li id="bar">bar</li>
  <li id="baz">baz
      <div>more Text</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to remove the text from everything except the last list, which is zero indexed as `2`. Because the zero index is a variable, I put this variable inside a span like this:

```
<span>2</span>
```

The variable in Jquery:

```
var qw = $('li:eq(' + $("span").text() + ')');
```

And finally the remove function:

```
$('body *').not(qw).contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).remove();
```

The problem is that the div inside the list is also being removed, but I really whant to keep it. I played around with the `('*')` selector but I can't seem to put it in the right place. For instance this doesn't work:

```
var qw = $('li:eq(' + $("span").text() + ')' + '*');
```

[Example at JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p83Rg/8/)

Comment: I'm not sure what this `all()` is you're talking about. If you're talking about the "all selector" that is the universal selector `*`. There is no such function called `all()` in jQuery.

Comment: @ BoltClock What are you talking about?? Wher did I state it is a function?? I specifically wrote "the all() selector"

Comment: `all()` as it is written in your question is functional notation. In case you were confusing the terms "function" and "selector", I'm telling you that there is no such *function*. If you're talking about a *selector*, there is no such selector called `all()` (or `:all()`) either, but there is `*` which selects all elements.

Comment: @Youss your question is really hard to understand what is where and what you want. Please, rephrase it

Comment: @BoltClock OK the all selector ('*')...

Comment: @roXon "The problem is that the div inside the list is also being removed, but I really whant to keep it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you've `qw` already selected (cached) and you want to remove the text nodes utilizing this cached element, try this

```
$('body *').not(qw).not($('*', qw)).contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).remove();
```

It filters out any elements that are descendants of `qw`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

**HTML**

```
<span id="indexToKeep">2</span>

<ul>
    <li id="foo">foo</li>
    <li id="bar">bar</li>
    <li id="baz">baz
        <div>more Text</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("li:not(:eq(" + $("#indexToKeep").text() + "))", "ul").remove();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AApCR/1/).

Comment: Can you please give me an example with `body *` included?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
var allButLast = $("li").not(":last");
```

References:

- http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/not/

Note you could also do:

```
var allButLast = $("li:not(:last)");
```

Reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

**Update:**

As per your comment, you can also do:

```
var qw = $('li:not(:eq(' + $("span").text() + '))');
```

> http://gurustop.net

Comment: I cant refer to the list in that way, I can only refer to it with the index number I put in span

Comment: So that would be  `$("li:not(index number 2)");`